# "E/android.hardware.audio@6.0-impl.ranchu: WriteThread::doWriteImpl:226: pcm_write failed with Operation not permitted" in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I figured out this error in my logcat in Android Studio. It is spamming all the time. My app is running perfectly, But I don't know why this error message is spamming all the time. Any solutions will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: is your logcat set to filter out only logs for your selected application ?

Comment: @a_local_nobody I have selected No filters. If I select Only selected application then it is not spamming

Comment: @a_local_nobody Yes, it is helpful and I am upvoting. If possible tell me the actual meaning of that error, not with reference to my app. Thank you.

Comment: i'm not sure what that error is exactly, but if it goes away by applying the filter then it isn't relevant to your app

Comment: @a_local_nobody Ok Thanks